# Messed up my SD card something awful. Cannot format, reporting bad sectors, bad partitions.. what can I use to repair?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, hardware-failure, sd-card

So, long story short - I created an image of my 16GB SD card used for my Raspberry Pi.  I bought a 32GB SD card, wrote the image on it and it is now totally bricked.

The SD card is brand new, just picked it up today.

Boot sector is all jacked up, partitions are all over the place, I cannot format it with any tools .. nothing seems to be able to fix it up.

It seems the logical geometry is out of whack.  Is there anything I can do to just start with a clean slate?  I've used various tools to try to rebuild the boot sector/partition table .. and nothing is working.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to linux?

Comment: @Paul I do.  I have a little linux media center sitting next to me I can ssh into if i need to

Comment: Have you tried using the 'official' sd card formatter?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yeah, it doesn't work.  It says it's write-protected, but it's not.  It doesn't have a lock switch, and I can freely modify files on the partition.  The issues with my SD bug out that formatter

Comment: What exact steps did you follow to write the image to the SD card? Was the SD card working fine before? Did you you try to use the **Delete** option available in TestDisk? What happens if you right-click any of the partitions in the Disk Management utility and choose **Delete Volume** from the context menu?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a few things, in this order -

First, use the [sd card association formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/) as per [the noobs installation guide](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md) - specifically make sure you have the "FORMAT SIZE ADJUSTMENT" setting to on.

If that dosen't work, boot into linux and use 'shred' on the *base* device of the sd card to wipe out the partition table and everything else on the drive. Create a new partition table with gparted or fdisk, and carry on as per normal.

I'd also recommend using noobs over a raw image if possible, if only to avoid this sort of thing happening.

Comment: I have tried the SD Card formatter, it says it's write protected (it's not, it doesn't even have a lock switch).  Whatever happened to my SD card is bugging out that program.  Thanks for the tip on NOOBS.. looks interesting.  I am using RetroPie though so that won't really work in this situation.  

I will try shred, thank you.  I've tried wiping the partition tables on windows and rebuilding with third party tools but that hasn't worked.  Will try on linux.